# PHP: display items from array to string NOT working

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with converting an array to individual strings and outputting the strings.  I'm trying to store each converted string into it's own variable and output each variable to the string using an echo statement.  I have already set up a mysqli connection. $connection is the mysqli connection.  I've already tried using serialize() and implode() functions.  There are four database colums (id, name, email, phonenumber). I commented out some code so you can see what I've been trying. I still can't seem to figure it out.  I've included my code below.  Thanks.

```
function get_random_info($connection)
{
$temp = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT RAND() * FROM distributors LIMIT 1");
 $info = $temp; 

 return $info;
}

//$random_distributor = serialize(get_random_info($con));
//$random_distributor = implode(get_random_info($con));

$random_distributor = $info;

//TEST WITH print_r
print_r ($random_distributor);

//$random_id = $random_distributor[0];
//$random_name = $random_distributor[1];
//$random_email = $random_distributor[2];
//$random_phonenumber = $random_distributor[3];

// TEST OUT INFORMATION. DISPLAY TO SCREEN.

echo "Random name is" . $random_name. "His id in the database is" . $random_id . ".
His email address is {$random_email} and his phone number is {$random_phonenumber}";
```

Comment: Neither you know about the local scope nor you know who to use mysqli_. If you have understood that it will be easy to solve for you.

Comment: You query should be `SELECT * FROM distributors ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. Also, you never actaully fetch the result set of the query in your function, which seems odd.  Where is the `get_random_info()` function even called?

Comment: @Mike Brant : I changed the query to SELECT * FROM distributors ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 .  I also un-commented out the four $random_ statements and it stiull does not echo out any of the strings.  There is just whitespace.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mike Brant: Would I want to use the serialize() function or the implode() function?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3417126 What would you be trying to use them for? If you are just trying to out the results of the database, there is no need.  You just need to read up on how to work while database result set (like `mysqli_fetch_array()1 function).

Comment: I figured it out with all of your help.  It works now.  I will post code solution by the end of the day.  It won't let me answer my own question right now because I am a new user.  Thanks!

Comment: I used: $row = mysqli_fetch_array(get_random_info($con),MYSQLI_ASSOC);
I also changed the echo statement to the following: echo "Random name is". $row["name"] . ". His id in the database is ". $row["id"]. ". His email address is ". $row["email"]. " and his phone number is ". $row["phonenumber"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some help from you guys.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Below is the solution.

```
<?php

function get_random_info($con)
{
    $random_distributor = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM distributors ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");  
    return $random_distributor;
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_array(get_random_info($con),MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// TEST OUT INFORMATION. DISPLAY TO SCREEN.

echo "Random name is ". $row["name"] . ". His id in the database is ". $row["id"]. ".  His email address is ". $row["email"]. " and his phone number is ". $row["phonenumber"];

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

these are all commented out so it couldn't possibly work.

```
//$random_id = $random_distributor[0];
//$random_name = $random_distributor[1];
//$random_email = $random_distributor[2];
//$random_phonenumber = $random_distributor[3];
```

and you have a function that you never call

```
get_random_info
```

Comment: Look at her/his code. He/she's trying to access a mysqli_result object like an array